# Energy difference between symmetric and antisymmetric wavefunctions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction

Is there any energy difference between a particle in a symmetric wavefunction and an identical particle in an identical potential but in a state with an anti-symmetric wavefunction?  Or is it case-dependent?

The full problem statement (from [this assignment](http://www.physics.utah.edu/~rogachev/5460/HW08_14.pdf)) is

[image: problem]

Comment: There is some confusion in your question. Either you mean a one-particle system that is symmetric w.r.t. some point or hypersurface, or you mean a multi-particle state (in Fock space), built out of one-particle states in a symmetric/antisymmetric way. In that case you're describing not one, but several particles.

Comment: The problem this question is based off of can be found here: http://www.physics.utah.edu/~rogachev/5460/HW08_14.pdf.  I have edited my question to include a link. It is problem 2 on that PDF.

Comment: Comment to the post (v2): It would be good if OP (or somebody else?) could try to make the question formulation self-contained, so one doesn't have to open the link to understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

If we stick to the Problem #2 you mentioned, then yes, there is an energy difference. Since seems there is no degeneracy from symmetry for $ \psi(r-a) \pm \psi(r+a)$, unless numerically accident.

$$ E_{\pm} = \langle \psi(r-a) \pm \psi(r+a)  | \hat{H} | \psi(r-a) \pm \psi(r+a) \rangle \tag{1} $$

$+,-$ correspond to $E_G,E_E$ in the Problem #2, respectively.

$E_G-E_E = 2 \left[ \langle \psi(r-a) | \hat{H} | \psi(r+a) \rangle + c.c. \right] $

$ =   2 \left[ \langle \psi(r-a) | \hat{H}_0 + \hat{H}'| \psi(r+a) \rangle + c.c. \right] $
$ =   2 \left[ \langle \psi(r-a) | E_0 + \hat{H}'| \psi(r+a) \rangle + c.c. \right] $
$ = 2 \left[ \langle \psi(r-a) |  \hat{H}'| \psi(r+a) \rangle + c.c. \right]  $
$ \tag{2} $

Here 
$$H_0:=-\frac{1}{2} \nabla^2 - \frac{1}{|r-a|}, H'= - \frac{1}{|r+a|} + \frac{1}{|2a|} $$ 
$c.c.$ denotes to complex conjugation. $E_0$ is the energy of hydrogen atom.

we have assumed $\langle \psi(r-a) | \psi(r+a) \rangle=0$ as mentioned in the Problem #2. Since in the last line of Eq. (2), $\langle \psi(r-a) | 1/2a |\psi(r+a) \rangle=1/2a \langle \psi(r-a) | \psi(r+a) \rangle = 0$, we have $E_G-E_E<0$

Comment: Some questions:  what is $c.c.$?  Could you show your math for how you get $E_G - E_E$ because I get that it equals $2 \left[ \langle \psi(r-a) | \hat{H} | \psi(r+a) \rangle + \langle \psi(r+a) | \hat{H} | \psi(r-a) \rangle \right] $
 .  And, what are $\hat{H}_A$ and $\hat{H}_b$?

Comment: c.c. denotes to complex conjugation. I have edited the equations and explained other symbols, since there are a few mistakes.